# How can I prevent users to read and write from or into respectively from my CouchDB database?

Tags: couchdb

I don't want other users to see my database and documents inside it. There is something read/write privilege to users. I don't have clear picture about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the database names you have to use a proxy server in front of the CouchDB.

If it's ok to see the names of the DBs but the doc read access should be restricted - you can use the security settings of each DB.

A more granular write access control is enabled by using the `validate_doc_update` function of a design document (which you have to create inside a db by your own).